# iOS: How to use operation queues to download large amount of data?

Tags: ios, image

I am developing an iOS application in which I have to download large data like images and videos locally on device. The data can be in GB's and there can be thousands of files to download. So, whats the best way to tackle this situation. Because it can have many failures like request time out etc.

Also I have to updated core data that if the file has been successfully downloaded or not.

Any best and simple way would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use ASIHTTPRequest. Although they have stopped further development but current version is enough to fulfil all your needs.

Comment: I have used it in my previous project. And it is not showing good results on IOS 7. Thats why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AFNetworking for that. it is a best API for dealing with web services now a days .you can download Latest AFNetworking API for iOS from github and.

you can use

```
  - (void)uploadImageAtUrl:(NSURL*)url
{
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImg.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"yourImg" fileName:@"yourImg.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    //Check progress
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Atleast you are not amongst those who just vote down your question just for the sake that they find that thing easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at AFNetworking framework, handles almost everything for you and probably faster then you could implement.

Also do the downloading on a background thread using GCD. I've had decent results downloading 50Mb files.